# How can the same function be provided without using the row_number() function in sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, flutter

The query below is working perfectly well if the user's phone supports sqlite version 3.25.0 or higher. Otherwise, as you can guess, the query doesn't work. How can I transform the code, without using the row_number () function?

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recipe_name) AS rn,
            rt.*
        FROM
            SyncRecipeIngredientTable sr
            JOIN RecipeIngredientTable ri ON ri.recipe_ingredient_id = sr.recipe_ingredient_id
            JOIN RecipeTable rt ON rt.recipe_id = sr.recipe_id
        WHERE ri.recipe_item_name in ("patates", "soğan", "su")
        GROUP by rt.recipe_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
    )
WHERE rn = 1
```

The database's ER diagram:
[image]

The expected result:
[image]

Comment: The ROW_NUMBER() function does not contain an ORDER BY clause, so it is not obvious which row of all that have the same recipe_name you want in the results. Post sample data of the results of the query and your expected result.

Comment: Also, which table contains the column `recipe_name`?

Comment: @forpas I edited the question please take a look

Comment: Please explain what you want the query to be doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff must not show repetitive records with the same recipe_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect recipes to have unique names.  If so, then the outer quer is simply not needed:

```
SELECT rt.*
FROM SyncRecipeIngredientTable sr JOIN
     RecipeIngredientTable ri 
     ON ri.recipe_ingredient_id = sr.recipe_ingredient_id JOIN
     RecipeTable rt
     ON rt.recipe_id = sr.recipe_id
WHERE ri.recipe_item_name in ('patates', 'soğan', 'su')
GROUP by rt.recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

If recipes can have duplicated names, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
WITH rt AS (
      SELECT rt.*
      FROM SyncRecipeIngredientTable sr JOIN
           RecipeIngredientTable ri 
           ON ri.recipe_ingredient_id = sr.recipe_ingredient_id JOIN
           RecipeTable rt
           ON rt.recipe_id = sr.recipe_id
      WHERE ri.recipe_item_name in ('patates', 'soğan', 'su')
      GROUP by rt.recipe_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
     )
SELECT rt.*
FROM rt
WHERE rt.recipe_id = (SELECT MAX(rt2.recipe_id)
                      FROM rt rt2
                      WHERE rt2.recipe_name = rt.recipe_name
                     );
```